# Why does this JS code work only when "console.log()" is present?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

This checkbox routine works only when `console.log("message")` is included. Remove "console.log()" and it stops working. What's wrong?

**Purpose:** When the user UNchecks any checkbox with `class="one-role"`, then the checkbox with `id="all-roles"` should get unchecked.

**JQUERY:**

```
// FAILS: This version (without console) does not uncheck "All"
$('.one-role').click(function() {
    if(! $(this).attr('checked'))
     $('#all-roles').prop('checked', false);
});


// WORKS: This version (with console) successfully unchecks "All"
$('.one-role').click(function() {
    if(! $(this).attr('checked'))
     console.log("one-role now unchecked");  // <--- without me, no worky!
     $('#all-roles').prop('checked', false);
}
```

**HTML FORM:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="include_role[]" value="all" checked="checked" id="all-roles">

<input type="checkbox" name="include_role[]" value="manager" checked="checked" class="one-role">
<input type="checkbox" name="include_role[]" value="owner" checked="checked" class="one-role">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/assets/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/assets/my_javascript.js"></script>
```

**What I've tried:**

I'm using Chrome on Windows 10.

My .js file is loaded last.

After changing my js file, I upload to server and `hard-refresh` (CTRL REFRESH) my browser.

--Puzzled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason why your code works is a stroke of luck: when you have no curly brackets/parenthesis after an `if` statement, only the first line will be part of the `if` conditional. In other words, your code:

```
$('.one-role').click(function() {
    if(! $(this).attr('checked'))
      console.log("one-role now unchecked");
      $('#all-roles').prop('checked', false)
}
```

Is actually equivalent to:

```
$('.one-role').click(function() {
    if(! $(this).attr('checked')) {
      console.log("one-role now unchecked");
    }

    $('#all-roles').prop('checked', false)
}
```

Which means that your `#all-roles` checkbox is **always unchecked**, and that gives the illusion of it working. Instead, you should be using this logic instead:

```
$('.one-role').change(function() {
  if (!this.checked)
    $('#all-roles').prop('checked', false);
});
```

---

**However, this is a very simplicistic interpretation of what I think you want the UI to be**. Based on your example, I suppose what you **actually** want is this:

- When *any* `.one-role` is unchecked, `#all-roles` should be unchecked
- When *all* `.one-role` is checked, `#all-roles` should be checked
- When `#all-roles` is unchecked, all `.one-role` elements should be unchecked
- When `#all-roles` is checked, all `.one-role` elements should be checked

That will require some modification to your logic:

```js
// Changes to any `.one-role `will influence status of all roles
$('.one-role').change(function() {
  // Check if all `.one-roles` are checked
  var count = $('.one-role').length;
  var checked = $('.one-role').filter(':checked').length;
  
  // If none are checked, uncheck `#all-roles`
  if (!checked) {
    $('#all-roles')
      .prop('checked', false)
      .prop('indeterminate', false);
    return;
  }
  
  // If some but not all are checked, use indeterminate state
  if (count !== checked) {
    $('#all-roles')
      .prop('checked', false)
      .prop('indeterminate', true);
    return;
  }
  
  // Otherwise, we check it
  $('#all-roles')
    .prop('checked', true)
     .prop('indeterminate', false);
});

// Checking `#all-roles` should toggle all `.one-role`
$('#all-roles').change(function() {
  $('.one-role').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="include_role[]" value="all" checked="checked" id="all-roles">

<input type="checkbox" name="include_role[]" value="manager" checked="checked" class="one-role">
<input type="checkbox" name="include_role[]" value="owner" checked="checked" class="one-role">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I'm studying your informative reply -- thank you.  FYI, when the form is loaded for the first time, every checkbox is checked and all available records are displayed. So, shoudn't the curly braces be unnecessary if `console.log()` is not present, because then the only conditional statement to be executed is `$('#all-roles').prop('checked', false);` ?

Comment: The solution to the exact question I asked is within your answer.  Changing `if(! $(this).attr('checked'))` to `if (!this.checked)` solved it. And, I'm going to implement your suggested logic because it's better than mine -- thank you! :-)